# "drush cache-rebuild" throwing driver not found error

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I am getting `[error]  could not find driver` for the command `drush cache-rebuild`

Below is the Drush and Drupal Version Details, Appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try the command with the `-vv` switch, which is `very verbose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using wampp with PostgreSQL where I enabled `pdo_pgsql, pgsql` from wampp applcation menu (`wampp> php > php extension`). It didn't work for me.

Step 1) run `php -m` in terminal,  in my case it didn't listed those php modules although it was showing enabled in wampp. So I went to `php.ini` and enabled those modules.

Step 2) `drush cr` or `drush cache-rebuild` clears cache from database, so make sure to put postgres path to system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. sudo composer update
2. run drush cr all

Answer (score 0):

Try using `drush cr` command. And if you are using ubuntu then you must use `sudo drush cr` command.